# What does `git add -A` really do?

Tags: git

According to [the git documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-add):

> -A
>   --all
>   --no-ignore-removal
>
> Update the index not only where the working tree has a file matching `<pathspec>` but also where the index already has an
>   entry. This adds, modifies, and removes index entries to match the
>   working tree.
>
> If no `<pathspec>` is given when -A option is used, all files in the
>   entire working tree are updated (old versions of Git used to limit the
>   update to the current directory and its subdirectories).

I understood this to mean that when I run `git add -A subdirectory`, that git effectively is doing this:

```
$ git update-index --again
$ git add subdirectory
```

However, upon doing a simple test in a local dummy git repository, it does not update files that are outside of `<pathspec>` but also have been staged. In fact, I can't find any difference in behavior with or without the `-A` option.

Can anyone explain the behavior of the `-A` option for `git add` (the git documentation's explanations are always a bit bitter to swallow)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `--no-ignore-removal` is a clue. It means that if a file *does not* appear in your working tree but *does* appear in the index - e.g. if you have `rm`ed it but not `git rm`ed it - then it will be removed from the index (as if you had `git rm`ed it).

Comment: In other words, read it as "where the index already has an entry **matching `<pathspec>`**".

Comment: `git add` already does this without the `-A` option. If a file is removed in the working copy but not the index, it shows up as "D" in short status. Newer versions of git will automatically stage removals when you run `git add <path>`. So is this a legacy option then?

Comment: Yes it is a legacy option. The default legacy behavior can be replicated by setting `--ignore-removal`.